# Trouble with widgets in Jupyter notebook

Tags: widget, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to follow this guide and I can't get past the first few lines.

https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/1c550518168311840ba8c810395598af85f51c58/examples/notebooks/Widget%20Basics.ipynb

First I run:

```
from ipywidgets import *
```

Which works fine, but then I run this:

```
IntSlider()
```

And it times out! I can't even interrupt the process. I have no idea why and for some reason Google is failing me. I know that there was an older version of ipywidgets, but as far as I could tell, this is the most updated version.

I've also tried:

```
%matplotlib inline
IntSlider()
```

I installed ipywidgets with:

```
pip install ipywidgets
```

I'm running:

Python 2.7.10
Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)
IPython 4.0.1

OSX El Capitan (v 10.11.1)
MacBook Pro (Mid 2015)

Any ideas? I'm new to widgets and I'd like to figure out how it all works, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

EDIT: I'm also using ipywidgets version 4.1.1, which is the current version as of this post.

EDIT2: Alright, I just re-installed ipywidgets and rebooted and one of those worked! Sometimes the simplest solution is the best.

Comment: what does `import ipywidgets` followed by `ipywidgets.__version__` show?

Comment: Looks like I'm using '4.1.1' which I think is the current version - editing original post to make this info more readily available.